# Meta Tag in HTML Mail is partly shown

Tags: html, email, meta-tags

We have vom .txt dokuments with our email content as HTML code.
Problem is, that we had to add some blank lines so the meta tag is not shown in the mails.
Until now, we had 5 blank lines, but with the Greek mails we need around 20 blank lines for this.
Is there a less ugly solution for this problem?

The affected meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

The Code in the Document:

```
Subject:




<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0," />
  <style type="text/css">
  //some css
  </style>
</head>
//followed by body
```

Example in Mail:

```
-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

The Mail is displayed as coded after this line.

Can someone please help?

Thank you!

Comment: This is not how it is supposed to work.  My guess is that something else entirely is wrong, and that the empty lines somehow mask the real problem.  Perhaps you could show the full source of a representative email message?  (This doesn't really seem like a programming question, though.)

Comment: I added the whole header.

Comment: You have a single `Subject:` header and no MIME headers at all?  Then it should be displayed as just text, not HTML.  Which client are you seeing this under?

Comment: you mean mail client?
Web.de and gmail
I didn't write the code für the mails, my work was just changing the translations, so I don't really know, what they thought, when they wrote this...

Answer (score 0):

Your message should not display as HTML at all.  We can only surmise that adding empty lines somehow exposes a bug in some webmail clients.  You should not be relying on this; you should send valid messages.  Here is a simple minimal example of a valid HTML email message.

```
From: you <your.address@example.com>
To: recipient <their.address@example.net>
Subject: whatever you like
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0," />
  <style type="text/css">
  //some css
  </style>
</head>
//followed by body
```

I don't think the `http-equiv` is even necessary any longer, given that the MIME content declaration already sets things up for properly displaying it, but YMMV.

The `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit` means lines have to be shorter than some 1,000 characters.  If that's a problem, maybe employ a different content-transfer-encoding (quoted-printable, perhaps; but then you have to program that, too).

Comment: From and To is set at another point.
I added the other two parts. Sadly, this destroyed the whole email.
I think I have to look at the notification system.